# How do I deal with d.ts files when publishing my typescript code to npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-publish

I have been following this article:

[How to create strongly-typed npm packages](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-create-strongly-typed-npm-modules-1e1bda23a7f4#.ja54n8ih7)

and have been trying to setup my typescript project to publish it to npm.

It all seems to make sense but what is not covered is how to deal with `d.ts` files.

My project looks somewhat like this:

```
src
  node
    server.ts
  browser
    client.ts
  common
    contracts.d.ts
```

so when I compile this with `"declaration": true` and `"outDir: "dist"` I get:

```
dist
  node
    server.js
    server.d.ts
  browser
    client.js
    client.d.ts
```

both my `server.ts` file and `client.ts` files have

```
import {SomeType} from "../common/contracts";
```

in so when someone else uses this package the typescript compilation will fail as `server.d.ts` and `client.d.ts` both still have this import.

Node will run fine though as `client.js` and `server.js` do NOT have this import. `tsc` must remove imports of `d.ts` files.

What I want to happen is for the `contracts.d.ts` file to be copied to the dist folder as part of the build. How do I do that as part of the `tsc` build?

### Current Workaround

What I am currently doing to get round this is rename my `contracts.d.ts` to just `contracts.ts` which means that all required files are present in the dist folder but it does mean that both the client and the server are having to load an empty `contracts.js` file that only contains

```
"use strict";
//# sourceMappingURL=contracts.js.map
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I have come up with quite a good solution to this.
I have moved my declaration files into a contracts folder so my project looks like this:

```
src
  node
    server.ts
  browser
    client.ts
dist
  node
    server.js
    server.d.ts
  browser
    client.js
    client.d.ts
contracts
    common.d.ts
```

I then just include the contracts folder in the npm package and import files using `../../contracts/common`. This path works both from the src folder when compiling and from the dist folder when building against this package.

Comment: Note that the folder is outside `src` and has to be included in `tsconfig.json` and in the `files` array of `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

If though the contracts are just types, I would still declare them in a `.ts` file. Or are the contracts generated from somewhere else?

Comment: They are just types but interfaces do not result in a JavaScript file so you put them in a .d.ts file to indicate to the compiler that it should not produce a js file.

Comment: interfaces never result in javascript code. But otherwise my bet would be to use triple slash paths `/// <reference path="etc" />`. But I think you will complicate your setup and tooling unnecessarily by using .d.ts files directly in this way.

Comment: Using them in the way that they are designed to be used? If you have a .ts file with just interfaces in then you end up with an empty js file that is then needlessly loaded by the browser.

Comment: bundling should prevent that?